# The tf.train.batch function is generating tensors batch of shape (8, 8, 299, 299, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow 1.5 GPU version on Windows 10.

This is the code.

```
targets = convert_to_onehot(labels_dir, no_of_features = num_classes)
assert targets.shape == (8,120), 'THE TARGETS SHAPE IS NOT CORRECT'
targets = tf.constant(targets, dtype = tf.float32)

Images = [] #TO STORE THE RESIZED IMAGES IN THE FORM OF LIST TO PASS IT TO tf.train.batch()
#Initally having a list of 8 images just for Testing purpose2
images = glob.glob(images_file_path)
i = 0
for my_img in images:
    image = mpimg.imread(my_img)[:, :, :3]
    #print (image.shape)
    image = tf.constant(image, dtype = tf.float32)
    Images.append(image)
    i = i + 1
    if i == 8:
        break

batch_size = 8
images, labels = tf.train.batch([Images, targets], batch_size = batch_size, num_threads = 1, capacity = batch_size)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (images.shape)
    print (labels.shape)
```

When I run the above code, it prints the shape (8, 8, 299, 299, 3) and (8, 8, 120) instead of (8, 299, 299, 3) and (8, 120).

The function required me to pass Images as a list and targets is a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

the first 8 is your batch size. change it to 4 and you will see it change accordingly.

What you are doing wrong is pre appending all images. `Images.append(image)`

This way your input already has a batch of 8 images, On top of that tf is also batching it, that's not how this is supposed to be done.

To solve this you will have to pass `enqueue_many=True` in `tf.train.batch`

`tf.train.batch([Images, targets], batch_size = batch_size, num_threads = 1, capacity = batch_size, enqueue_many=True)`

Read more here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The tensors are of correct shape now but when I feed them to the graph during my training step, I get the following error: `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float and shape [?,120]
  [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,120], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]`

Comment: Not enough details Ashutosh, sorry brother, I would suggest you start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

To the arguments in tf.train.batch add in the argument `enqueue_many = True`, the default is `False`. This tells tensorflow that the first dimension is an index of your samples.

Source: tensorflow documentation. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch